# How can I sort this "matrix" of data?

Tags: sorting, matrix

I run a sporting website, and it's often useful to rank people against each other based on their previous meetings.

See this example set of data:

[image]

On the left is the raw "unsorted" view.  On the right is the correctly sorted (in my opinion) list.

Each square shows the number of times they've competed against each other, and the percentage of victories.  They're shaded based on the percentage.

I have this in a webpage, with "up" and "down" controls alongside each row, and I can manually nudge them around until I get what I want.

I'm just not quite sure of the best way to automate this.

The numbers at the end of each row are a quick idea I roughed out, and equal to the sum across the row of (percentage-50 * column number).  As you can see, they do a fairly good job, with only the first two rows being "wrong".  They don't give any weight to number of meetings though, only the win percentage.

The final-column numbers change depending on the row order as well, as can be seen by comparing the left and right tables in the image, so sorting on the initial values wouldn't work that well.  Looping a sort + re-calc a couple of times might do the job.

I expect I can cobble something together to make this work... but I feel SO will have some **much** better ideas, and I'm all ears.

Comment: A quick thought: It's possible that A beats B more than 50% of the time, B beats C more than 50% of the time, and C beats A more than 50% of the time.  What is "supposed" to happen then?

Comment: It is possible, but it's an edge case.  Normally you can separate on how they compare to others.  If there's no way of splitting then grouping them together as a tie would be adequate.

Answer (score 1):

A [tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_%28graph_theory%29) is a graph in which there is exactly one directed edge between every pair of vertices; to create such a graph from your input, you could make a graph with a vertex for each player, and then "point" each edge between two players in the direction of the player who won a majority of games (you will need to break ties somehow).

If you do this, and *if* there are no cycles A > B > ... > A of the type I mentioned in my comment in this graph, then the graph is *transitive*, and you can order the players using a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of the graph.  This takes just linear time in the number of edges, i.e. O(n^2) for n players.

If there *are* such cycles, then there's no "perfect" ordering of players: any ordering will place at least one player after some player that they have beaten.  In that case, a reasonable alternative is to look for orderings that minimise the number of these "edge violations".  This turns out to be a well-studied NP-hard problem in computer science called (Minimum) Feedback Arc Set in Tournaments (FAST).    A [feedback arc set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_arc_set) is a set of directed edges ("arcs") which, if deleted from the graph, would leave a graph with no directed cycles -- which can then be easily turned into an order using topological sort as before.

[This paper](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/tfas4.pdf) describes a recent attack on the problem.  I haven't read the paper, but this is an active area of research and so the algorithm is probably quite complicated -- but it might give you ideas about how to create a simpler algorithm that runs slower (but acceptably fast on such small instances), or how to create a heuristic.

Comment: I feel like I wish I hadn't asked! :)

Comment: Hehe :) It's sometimes annoying how "sharp" the transitions between problems can be: your problem initially seems a lot like ordinary sorting, which everyone knows can be solved in O(n log n) time with several well known algorithms!

Comment: Is it possible to provide a "weight" to each edge?  The code samples I've looked at (e.g. http://blog.calcatraz.com/php-topological-sort-function-384) only have directions on the edges, e.g "A normally beats B" or "B normally beats A".  Wouldn't it be beneficial to specify a precise number on each "edge"?  Or does graph theory not work like that?  /newb.  Thanks!

Comment: Sure, and this might be beneficial -- e.g., you could then look for a minimum-*weight* set of directed edges to delete, which might give a "better-seeming" result.  I don't know of algorithms for this, but on such small instances brute force is viable.

Comment: The set was only a simple "example" for the post; 100 people would be more typical.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to j_random's answer, you can isolate cycles using something like [Tarjan's strongly connected components algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan's_strongly_connected_components_algorithm). Within a strongly connected component, you could use another method for sorting the items.